# Dockerfile - how do I pass passwords from a file into ENV variables?

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

I want to store all the confidential environment variables - POSTGRES_PASSWORD, SECRET_KEY, etc, in a separate file, so that they don't get committed to github.

How can I include these variables into the Dockerfile, so that I could use them to run migrations and stuff like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running each container through your CLI .. you should pass your variables as an argument as a string in the format `-e "foo=bar"`.

The better way i can suggest is if you're using something like `docker-compose` (which i recommend) for deployment. you can set all your passwords in a `.env` file and reference them in your docker-compose file.

```
web:
    container_name: web
    env_file: .env
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I've tried doing that, but unfortunately, it seems that if I specify env_file in docker-compose, variables are not accessible during the build process. I want to run migrations and launch a server from the Dockerfile, but it doesn't work....

Comment: Ooh, nevermind, I have figured out what was wrong! I needed to run migrations after the build is complete, with CMD, instead of trying to run them during the build with RUN.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chef, The best and expected practice is to use Chef Data bags -- see https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html

Databags allow you to commit these keys to your repo in an encrypted form; upon deployment, they are decrypted and usable for your environment files.

Besides using chef, the option mentioned by the poster using `compose` and converge is your best bet.